# set ThrowableRenderer via log4j.xml

Tags: java, log4j

I need to set up a custom stacktrace format with `log4j`. If I use log4j property `log4j.throwableRenderer=package.ThrowableRenderer` everything works fine. How can I accomplish the same with `log4j.xml` format? The only article I found with both log4j.xml format and ThrowableRendered is [here](http://osdir.com/ml/log4j-user.logging.apache.org/2010-02/msg00016.html) .But this doesn't work. The property isn't setting to logger and breakpoints don't work in debug too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration strict="true" status="info">
    <ThrowableRenderer class="package.ThrowableRenderer"/>
    <Appenders>
        <Appender filePattern="file{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
                  fileName="file.log" name="logfile" type="RollingFile">
            <Layout type="PatternLayout">
                <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %m%n</Pattern>
            </Layout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="false" interval="1"/>
            </Policies>
        </Appender>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
         ...
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

How do I set the `ThrowableRenderer` with `log4j.xml` or where I can find the documentation to read about it?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that log4j doesn't support ThrowableRenderer. Instead you can extend [ThrowablePatternConverter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/ThrowablePatternConverter.html) and create a new [ConverterKey](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/ConverterKeys.html). Afterwords just add the key to the convertorPattern like

```
<Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} %m%n%YOUR_CREATED_KEY</Pattern>
```